# disappearance of all the tabs in my joomla administration interface

Tags: joomla-3.x, administrator

I just noticed a my surprise the disappearance of all the tabs in my administration interface... (see attachment) You should know that all components work perfectly. For example when I type http://localhost/notaire_v1/administ...p?option= * I can access the content. I have just more access has different menus and I do not know why...

Could you help me please?

I already followed the instructions that it offers me an attachment

[image]

Comment: try logging out then back in. Try clearing your browser cache. Try updating to the latest version of Joomla if you haven't already

Comment: Thank for your comment. I have the last version of joomla and i have this situation in any browsers in my computer(Chromium and Firefox)..

Comment: Have you tried opening up Firebug or Chrome Dev Tool and seeing if the content is there but being hidden?

Comment: Yes but in this version i have not <ul id="menu" class="nav">*</ul> in <div class="nav-collapse collapse"></div> So it does not in my administration code source :-/

Comment: Have you tried or been able to clear your joomla cache?

Answer (score 2):

This happened to a client of mine once. The way I solved it was by downloading the all purpose upgrade package file from Joomla website.  It doesn't matter if the core is already up to date, but make sure to get correct upgrade file.

For instance, if you're on 3.4.4, download the 3.4.x package.  Once downloaded manually type in administration url to install extensions, select the downloaded upgrade package and install.  Once done, refresh and see if that fixes it.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Good advice. The standard install is at: `/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer`